# ggplot2 add offset to jitter positions

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data that looks like this

```
df = data.frame(x=sample(1:5,100,replace=TRUE),y=rnorm(100),assay=sample(c('a','b'),100,replace=TRUE),project=rep(c('primary','secondary'),50))
```

and am producing a plot using this code

```
ggplot(df,aes(project,x)) + geom_violin(aes(fill=assay)) + geom_jitter(aes(shape=assay,colour=y),height=.5) + coord_flip()
```

which gives me this

[image: violin plot with points]

This is 90% of the way to being what I want.  But I would like it if each point was only plotted on top of the violin plot for the matching assay type.  That is, the jitterred positions of the points were set such that the triangles were only ever on the upper teal violin plot and the circles in the bottom red violin plot for each project type.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `interaction` between assay & project:

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x = interaction(assay, project), y=x)) + 
     geom_violin(aes(fill=assay)) +  
     geom_jitter(aes(shape=assay, colour=y), height=.5, cex=4) 
p +  coord_flip()
```

The labeling can be adjusted by numeric scaled x axis:

```
# cbind the interaction as a numeric
df$group <- as.numeric(interaction(df$assay, df$project))
# plot
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=group, y=x, group=cut_interval(group, n = 4))) + 
     geom_violin(aes(fill=assay)) +  
     geom_jitter(aes(shape=assay, colour=y), height=.5, cex=4) 
p +  coord_flip() + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1.5, 3.5), labels = levels(df$project))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the desired result, it is probably best to use `position_jitterdodge` as this gives you the best control over the way the points are 'jittered':

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = project, y = x, fill = assay, shape = assay, color = y)) + 
  geom_violin() + 
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.9,
                                              jitter.width = 0.5,
                                              jitter.height = 0.2),
              size = 2) + 
  coord_flip()
```

which gives:

[image]